# Passing a proxy for host before hitting URLs mentioned in Nginx/forward proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

I need to pass a host proxy URL to connect to other URLs mentioned as proxy pass in nginx.

Example: If I have to connect to google.com through a Linux server box, I have to set proxy as xyz.org:80 and only then I can connect to google.com.

So how can I achieve it in nginx config?

My Nginx config file sample goes like this:

```
    server{
       listen     80;
       server_name   *;
      return 301     https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location / {
      sendfile            on;
      try_files           $uri $uri/ /index.html
                          /keepalive.html;
    }
    location /xyz{
       proxy_pass     google.com/
    }
```

Here, I need to pass my proxy xyz.org:80 in the Nginx config itself and only then I can connect to google.com/.

So basically, every request from my server box should pass via xyz.org:80 to the proxy_pass location mentioned in nginx config.

I tried mapping the http host and served host and passing it in the location but it is not working:

```
map $http_host $served_host {
        default $http_host;
        xyz.org:80 www.google.com;
    }

location /xyz{
           proxy_pass     google.com/;
         proxy_set_header Host $served_host;
        }
```

Comment: Much of this question is a copy+paste from yesterday's question, so it seems to be a re-ask of much the same thing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer - I am sorry for this, will keep that in mind, I wasn't able to edit the previous question so had to publish a new one.

Comment: It's odd that it did not let you edit the old one. What do you get if you [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46978734/edit)? That should take you straight to the editor of that question.

Comment: I have combined it as a duplicate, can't delete it now, earlier when I was raising the question I was in a hurry and wasn't able to edit it, so re-creating the question seemed easier. 

Anyways, any idea on this question? @halfer